# Why doesn't my database load from Heroku ClearDB when in Heroku app?

Tags: database, heroku, web

I built a php based website on the cloud9(C9) ide and I have a database based in heroku. The database works and information is retrieved when running it on my cloud (All tables requested in code appear where they should be). But when I push all my code to Heroku to the same application hosting the database, it fails to retrieve the information, no error codes shown, just a blank portion of the page. All Heroku credentials are correct because cloud9 can still pull from Heroku and I can physically see my database loaded on MySql Workbench on the Heroku server, so it is there.

When ran in the development environment cloud9 provides my code was pulling data out the clearDB database just fine, but when this code is pushed to Heroku and ran in Heroku, I receive a different result. The website design is there, but when I press the management tab there are not items from the ClearDB database present. Below you will see images of the differences between the code being ran in cloud9 and heroku.[image: Build on Cloud9 ide when I press the 'management tab']

[image: Build on Heroku When I press the management tab]

[image: The database exists on the Heroku server]

[image: Heroku logs, everything looks okay]

Application logs

> 2018-05-28T07:52:36.460199+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/CoffeeOverview.php" host=serene-shelf-61592.herokuapp.com request_id=80ec77fc-9fdd-4ffb-a325-955a41a85493 fwd="198.189.249.57" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=500 bytes=530 protocol=https
>   2018-05-28T07:52:36.459705+00:00 app[web.1]: [28-May-2018 07:52:36 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /app/Model/CoffeeModel.php on line 30
>   2018-05-28T07:52:36.460137+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.111.216.133 - - [28/May/2018:07:52:36 +0000] "GET /CoffeeOverview.php HTTP/1.1" 500 340 "https://serene-shelf-61592.herokuapp.com/Management.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36
>   2018-05-28T08:19:47.074063+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/Management.php" host=serene-shelf-61592.herokuapp.com request_id=91a804d7-81f2-4fed-b3da-d922e2438cee fwd="185.20.6.84" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=1472 protocol=http
>   2018-05-28T08:19:47.074422+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.41.164.211 - - [28/May/2018:08:19:47 +0000] "GET /Management.php HTTP/1.1" 200 1301 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (TweetmemeBot/4.0; +http://datasift.com/bot.html) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0
>   2018-05-28T08:56:00.991844+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
>   2018-05-28T08:56:00.993076+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
>   2018-05-28T08:56:01.900896+00:00 app[web.1]: Going down, terminating child processes...
>   2018-05-28T08:56:01.883618+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
>   2018-05-28T08:56:01.993121+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
>    Autoscroll with output Save
>   heroku.com Blogs Careers Documentation

Comment: Did you configure your database url in heroku config vars?

Comment: @jusermar10 Yes I did, it almost seems like you cannot have the project app in the same app as the ClearDB database. Do they need to be in separate applications?

Comment: Thats not true. How is your ClearDB configured in heroku? I assume you configured it as a add-on in your Project app.

Comment: @jusermar10 yes it is an add-on, basically I went to resources once a blank app was created on heroku and chose clearDB to create a database then it automatically assigned the Config vars of clearDB. That is about all I did, then used the credentials, username, password host, etc from the clearDB for the credentials.php file in my application.

Comment: What is your Heroku application logs saying? There should be some clue on whats happening. Please put that up as well.

Comment: @jusermar10 I just put the logs in the question, no errors shown. Link to the management tab here, clicking the overview link should return all of the coffee in the database in table format. >https://serene-shelf-61592.herokuapp.com/Management.php

Comment: Thats your build and deployment activity log. I mentioned about application log which you can be able to access via your heroku dashboard like `https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/<your-app-name>/logs` or you may add a free logging add-on called Papertrail which is easy to use.

Comment: @jusermar10 Oh okay, I posted the activity logs on the question now. Please view.

Comment: By looking at the logs, looks like you are trying to call a function `mysql_connect()` in line 30 of `CoffeeModel.php` which is not defined. Please check. Also, your log says `Management.php` loads just fine. Issue is only with `CoffeeOverview.php` Am I correct?

Comment: @jusermar10 There was no issue with CoffeeModel.php in cloud9 when building. Could this half to do with the mysql function being deprecated? I think cloud 9 still supports this older function, but maybe Heroku does not?

Comment: I'm not sure about the deprecated php function. Give it a try by replacing it with the latest one.